# oracle sql: how do i sum different data points in a select statment?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

i'm trying to return a sum which is the total of multiple rows of data that are returned. i'm trying to return data that shows an employee, account, and department. i want the sum of salary paid by those three data points. i also want a sum just by employee to show how their salary was distributed. an example is below. any help would be appreciated.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VQwx.jpg)

Comment: Please share the query you have came up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with different groups in a windowing clause using the `SUM` analytic function.

```
SELECT employee
  , account
  , dept
  , SUM (salary) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) AS employee_salary
  , SUM (salary) OVER (PARTITION BY dept) AS dept_salary_paid
  , SUM (salary) OVER (PARTITION BY account) AS acct_salary_paid
FROM mytable
```

I'm not sure if these groupings are exactly what you want (perhaps I misinterpreted your question) but it should give you the right idea. Windowing clauses give you more flexibility and allow you to group sums by different values, whereas a `GROUP BY` forces a single grouping per `SELECT`.

Edit, based on your most recent update:

You don't need a `GROUP BY` and a windowing clause. You can do two different `OVER(PARTITION BY ....)` clauses, so it would look like this:

```
select employee
, activity
, SUM (salary_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY employee, activity) AS "total salary by employee and activity"
, SUM (salary_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) AS "total salary by employee"
from mytable where employee = 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

what fhossfel wrote is basically how i want it to work. 
here is what i have tried:

select employee, activity, SUM (salary_amt), SUM (salary_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) AS "total salary by employee" 
from mytable 
where employee = 'xxx' 
group by employee, activity

i'm getting the error that sum by employee is not a group by expression

Comment: See edits in my answer. Also, this should probably be an edit to your question, not an answer in and of itself.

Answer (score -1):

This will return the sum of each employee's salary

```
SELECT employee, SUM(salary)
FROM Table
GROUP BY employee
```

Comment: This doesn't adequately answer the question, and I'm not sure it's really helpful to be honest. They wanted multiple sums. This could be done using window clauses (as @McGlothlin used) or through join logic...

Comment: The last two sentences of the question are being addressed here. He asks for a sum by employee and then states that any information helps.

Answer (score -2):

Building upon what McGothlin has already posted:

```
SELECT employee
  , account
  , dept
  , salary
  , SUM (salary) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) AS "total salary by employee"
  , ROUND(salary / SUM (salary) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) * 100) || '%' AS "salary distribution"
FROM mytable
```

Comment: So, what value, exactly, did you add from the answer you stole?

Comment: I have added the percentage calculation so the query actually return the requested result. Have you actually looked at the attached screenshot?